# Symfony 4 - How to dynamically add field in an entity?

Tags: mysql, symfony, symfony4

I want to have a form where I can add new fields (columns) in an specific entity. Is there a function for this?

Kind regards

Comment: Have you tried to use scheme manager to get access to metadata scheme and database structure?

Comment: No, I didn't try this. :) What will the schema manager do?

Comment: It will give you access to database structure.

Comment: Please describe your use-case in more details. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your request is uncommon so there are great chances that you designed your database structure wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a whole column to the table through an HTML form is a weird use case.
If you want to stick to the ORM way of managing the persisted data, you'll have to dynamically add properties to existing entities, which might be a sign of bad schema design.

What I would guess you probably need is an automated way to add this column to your Entity. In such a case I would use the [maker bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html).

Supposing that your Entity is called Employee, all you have to do is to type in the following command:

```
bin/console make:entity
```

When you'll be asked for the Entity name, enter **Employee**. The interpreter will tell you that this entity exists and if you want to extend it with news fields, and there you go.